# How to properly collapse MySQL rows into a single list

Tags: mysql, database, coalesce, sql-server-group-concat

I have a query of the form

```
SELECT pub.id, topic.id, pub.title, etc... 
FROM pub, topic, link
WHERE (matching logic)
```

which returns in the form

```
pub.id  |  topic.id  |  pub.title
---------------------------------
x1      |  a         |  y1
x1      |  b         |  y1
x1      |  ...       |  y1

x2      |  c         |  y2
x2      |  d         |  y2
x2      |  ...       |  y2
```

what I really want is a response of the form

```
pub.id  |  topic.id  |  pub.title
---------------------------------
x1      |  a, b ...  |  y1
x2      |  c, d ...  |  y2
```

(I don't think the matching logic is important, but I'll post it if necessary.)

I've tried `group_concat()` and `coalesce`, but nothing works. Any help?

Comment: How you have tried `group_concat` can you post that query ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you remember to include `GROUP BY` in your `GROUP_CONCAT` test?
You cannot concatenate a group if you don't group the data.

Here's a working example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5cd63/2

It should amount to:

```
SELECT pub.id, GROUP_CONCAT(topic.id SEPARATOR ','), pub.title
FROM pub, topic
WHERE (matching logic)
GROUP BY pub.id, pub.title
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you! I had entirely forgotten about the `GROUP BY`, of course.